# How to create a JUnit TemporaryFolder with subfolders

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit-rule

I would like to create a JUnit TemporyFolder that represents the baseFolder of such a tree:

```
baseFolder/subFolderA/subSubFolder
          /subFolderB/file1.txt
```

As far as I understand I can setUp a TemporaryFolder and than can create with "newFolder()" pseudo Folders that are located in that very folder. But How can I create layers underneath? Especially in a way that is cleaned up after the test.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`temporaryFolder.newFolder(String... folderNames)` takes the whole hierarchy as parameters:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    File child = temporaryFolder.newFolder("grandparent", "parent", "child"); //...

    assertEquals("child", child.getName());
    assertEquals("parent", child.getParentFile().getName());
    assertEquals("grandparent", child.getParentFile().getParentFile().getName());
    System.out.println(child.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

It passes the tests and prints:

```
/var/folders/.../T/junit8666449860303204067/grandparent/parent/child
```

Comment: What about the file inside the subfolder "file1.txt"? How to create it?

Comment: Do TemporaryFolder instances get automatically deleted? This says they "should be deleted": https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html. This says they're "guaranteed to be deleted": https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.9/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html.

Comment: @JWoodchuck I think the idea is that there are exceptional cases where the folder will not be deleted successfully: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494459/why-isnt-junit-temporaryfolder-deleted#comment54739758_16494459

Answer (score 0):

TemporaryFolder has a method `newFolder(String...folderNames)` that allows you to create subdirectories.

```
tempFolder.newFolder("subFolderA", "subSubFolder")
```

http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html#newFolder(java.lang.String...)